# Surface Plasmon Resonance (SPR) Predicting Molecular Weight Limit?

Tags: molecular-biology, toxicology

Just asking, can we predict how low molecular weight (LMW) analyte our SPR system can detect based on our LOD (limit of detection) and our sensitivity on another protein detection? So right now our developed system can detect alpha-synuclein (14 kDa) with LOD around 5fg/ml. Can we predict how LMW can we detect? Is there any reference paper or something. Because as far as my knowledge we can get the change of RII based on the experiments first. But right now my case is I want to test the limit of our SPR devices to detect LMW (I'm choosing what LMW analytes to buy right now)

Thank you! any discussion or comments are very appreciated

Comment: Can you please expand your acronyms?

Comment: @jakebeal sure!